# What is the proper Google OAuth2 authorization process for asp.net core apps hosted by clients on many unknown domains or no domain (IP)

Tags: asp.net-core, google-api, google-authentication

We are developing asp.net core applications that will require sending emails with gmail among other providers (client accounts). This applications will not be hosted by us but by many of our clients.
The application may be hosted on their domain or no domain at all (IP address only).

I am struggling with which authorization process I should use since I can not use the Javascript client  or any redirect URI method due to unknown origin/domain. I also can not use localhost origin since there is no way for me to start a local http server from a browser. Programmatic extraction is deprecated. The only thing I am left with is manual copy/paste but apart from it being very user unfriendly Google documentation states that that might be deprecated in the future as well.

Am I missing something?
Please point me in the right direction as to how I should proceed.